# Puppet gives 'Checksumfile /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml is corrupt' error

Tags: state, puppet

I am getting a weird error when I trying to run Puppet in one of my nodes:

```
Error: Checksumfile /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml is corrupt (syntax error on line 77, col 12: ` !binary ? "RmlsZVsvdmFyL3d3dy9sYXVuY2hib3gvYXBwL2NhY2hlL3dlYXRoZXIvZnIu\nc2FpbnQtc+liYXN0aWVuLXN1ci1s 2lyZS5wbmdd\n"'); replacing
```

I have puppet running in over than 100 nodes and I am getting this error in 3 of them. Puppet used to run fine in these boxes though.

1. Puppet master configuration:

   - centos 6.4
   - puppet 3.3.2
   - it is using passenger / httpd
   - it is using puppet dashboard for reports
   - ruby packages:

     - libselinux-ruby-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.x86_64
     - ruby-1.8.7.352-12.el6_4.x86_64
     - ruby-augeas-0.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
     - ruby-devel-1.8.7.352-12.el6_4.x86_64
     - rubygem-daemon_controller-1.1.5-1.el6.noarch
     - rubygem-fastthread-1.0.7-2.el6.x86_64
     - rubygem-json-1.5.5-1.el6.x86_64
     - rubygem-passenger-3.0.19-1.el6.x86_64
     - rubygem-passenger-native-3.0.19-1.el6.x86_64
     - rubygem-passenger-native-libs-3.0.19-1.el6_1.8.7.352.x86_64
     - rubygem-rack-1.1.0-2.el6.noarch
     - rubygem-rake-0.8.7-2.1.el6.noarch
     - rubygems-1.3.7-4.el6_4.noarch
     - ruby-irb-1.8.7.352-12.el6_4.x86_64
     - ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-12.el6_4.x86_64
     - ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.352-12.el6_4.x86_64
     - ruby-rgen-0.6.5-1.el6.noarch
     - ruby-shadow-1.4.1-13.el6.x86_64
2. One of the nodes that I am getting corrupted state:

   - centos 6.4
   - puppet 3.3.2
   - ruby packages:

     - libselinux-ruby-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.x86_64
     - ruby-1.8.7.352-13.el6.x86_64
     - ruby-augeas-0.4.1-1.el6.x86_64
     - ruby-devel-1.8.7.352-13.el6.x86_64
     - rubygem-json-1.5.5-1.el6.x86_64
     - rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch
     - ruby-irb-1.8.7.352-13.el6.x86_64
     - ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-13.el6.x86_64
     - ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.352-13.el6.x86_64
     - ruby-rgen-0.6.5-1.el6.noarch
     - ruby-shadow-1.4.1-13.el6.x86_64

I've tried to delete the file `/var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml` and then run puppet again. I don't get error in the first puppet running. However, the error starts again after the first puppet running.

I tried to Google it but I found nothing useful so far.

Comment: I've just figured it out. Puppet was trying to change the permission of a file that was deployed recently and there was a space in the name of the file, something like 'example of-file.png'. For some reason, puppet cannot do the checksumfile for it.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet was trying to change the permission of a file that was deployed recently and there was a space in the name of the file, something like 'example of-file.png'. For some reason, puppet cannot do the checksumfile for it.